# How to stop a while loop from running infinatly by making it stop when there are no more values in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make pull key => value pairs out of an array by using a do { ....} while {there are values left inside the array.

I am using a function to query mysql for and then to insert all the values inside an array

```
function table_array($query) {

    $table_array = array();
    $data_fetched = false;
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if (!$data_fetched) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $table_array[$key] = $value;
                //$data_fetched = true;
                } 
            }
        }
    return $table_array;
}
```

and then i am using another loop to extract the data from the array

```
function get_table($table_array) {


    $header_written = false;
    echo "<table border=1>";

    if ($table_array) {

        do {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($table_array as $columns => $values) {
                echo "<td> {$values} </td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

        }while ($table_array);

        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

However this causing my loop to run infinitely , why can't i use it just as though i would be doing while mysql_fetch_assoc is true.

I tried using a flag but that will stop it running after only one record is being extracted.

Answer (score 2):

What you really need here are two `foreach` loops. The outer iterates over rows, and the inner iterates over columns:

```
echo "<table>";
// Iterates over rows
foreach ($table_array as $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
  // Iterates over columns (table cells)
  foreach ($row as $col=>$value) {
    echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
  } 
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Though your fetching process works, it can be simplified and improved.  You don't need a `foreach` to assign columns to your `$table_array`.  You can simply append the whole fetched row using the `[]` syntax.  Not sure what the purpose of `$data_fetched` was, so I removed that as well

```
 while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        // Use the [] syntax to append the whole row onto $table_array
        // No need to add each column of the fetched row separately
        $table_array[] = $array;        
  }
```

Finally, the reason it didn't work the way you setup your do-while is that iterating over a regular array is not similar to fetching from a MySQL result set.  The fetch calls will eventually return FALSE when no rows remain.  Unless you are actively removing elements from an array while iterating over it, and eventually deleting the empty array, it will always evaluate to a boolean TRUE.

Comment: the problem i am having is only in the second function which takes values already extracted from mysql.

I am still having that issue based on your solution it still just outputs the same value multiple times as opposed to iterating each key => value pair in the array

Comment: @PHPSushaRolls If it's outputting the same value each time, then either 1) you did not copy my code exactly or 2) your results array does not have the structure you think it does. `var_dump($table_array)` to see what's actually inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either `foreach($array as $key => $value){ ... }` or `do{ ... } while ($array)`.

You should not use both, as you only have one set of data to loop over. I would stick with foreach as it is safer, and can do exactly what you need.

If you feel you need to use a do/while, then you need to pop a value off the $table_array each time you are inside the loop. This way, the $table_array will become empty at some point. Currently, in your code, the $table_array is always full so the while loop continues endlessly.

Comment: The foreach (..){..}; will only run once it needs a to be nested in a while or do...while loop for it to be able to run foreach value in the array right now it is only returning one key => value pair from the array.